# data always getting from the previous databse not from the new database

Tags: sql-server

I am facing an issue from sql server that

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
"Select Role from Login where username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password   '" + textBox2.Text + "'  ",
con);
```

My sql command always get data from the pervious database not from the new one.

Comment: How do you define `con`?  Your issue seem to be with your connection, not your query.  But, be aware, building query like this if VERY dangerous.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that need to be addressed.

Comment: **WARNING**: Never, **EVER** store passwords as plain-text. **ALWAYS** use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection(con) is pointing to your old database change it to your new database.

Comment: That has got to be it.  create a new con object from scratch - make sue it has the new database target in its setup   It is hard to overlook the password plain text problems to see the actual problem that was asked.